# Using XLR to Stereo jack for looping and panning signals, is it a problem?

Tags: audio-recording, stereo, cable, mono

I'm working on a looping set up. I have three mic's around my drum set going into a mixer and then i pan them to one side. I'll use this side to output the whole drums as 1 signal into an RC-30 looper (which has jack inputs) using the XLR output of my mixer. i've also plugged in my base guitar amp and panned it to the other side, using this output to also send 1 signal (using the other XLR output) to my looper. Then from my looper there will be two sepperate outputs to go into my multitrack recorder so i can mix these channels independetly.

But, i accidentilly bought two XLR to stereo jack cables. Will this be a problem in panning the instruments? Will some of the sound leak or will i only be able to get either left or right?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this be a problem in panning the instruments?

No.

A cable with XLR and a 1/4" TRS (Tip Ring Sleeve) connector is NOT a stereo cable, it's a balanced cable. Either your 1/4" input is balanced and you get better signal to noise ratio and great hum rejection. Or your 1/4" input is unbalanced and it will simply short out the out of phase component of the balanced XLR signal.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering!

So the jack cables which have 2 black rings [like this](https://media.cablematic.com/__sized__/images_1000/xn08600-01-thumbnail-1080x1080-70.jpg) are balanced and it has nothing to do with stereo or mono?

Comment: They are used for either purpose, but if they are connected to a single XLR on the other end it's clearly designed to be a balanced connection.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!

Comment: To be precise: it doesn't depend on the cable, it does depend how the input is designed that you plug the cable into, The RC-30 has separate L/R inputs, so that works fine. If it had a single TRS stereo input, you would need some sort of a splitter

Comment: Thanks! I was just confused because the specific cables i talked about are advertised as 'stereo jack' cables. But thanks, i've tried it and it didn't bleed through at all!